# Rails respond_to format HTML Json Not workng with params

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, format

I am creating a Rails-Angularjs RESTful app. where a rails controller index action needs to generate a json for the Angularjs Front-end. The index action receives a parameter, which must be used as filter in the query to the DB. If I don't use the parameters everything works angular shows results. But, if I add the received parameter to the query, it doesn't work.

This the action index using the parameter in the query:
     def index
        @project_id = params[:project_id] 
        @tickets = PrintingTicket.where(project_id: @project_id)

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @tickets }
    end
 end
```

This is the action index not using the parameter to filter info in the query:

```
 def index
    @project_id = params[:project_id] 
    @tickets = PrintingTicket.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @tickets }
    end
 end
```

I noticed that the index action is executed twice, once for HTML and one for JSON. Project_id has valid information the first run, ad is 'nil' the second run.

By observing the console, on both cases, it shows the parameter at the beginning `Parameters: {"project_id"=>"5982a8799f911d0318054997"}` but, in the case where I use the parameter, the parameter has 'nil' at the end, as you can see on the log:

```
    Started GET "/projects/5982a8799f911d0318054997/tickets" for ::1 at 2017-11-18 21:50:34 -0800
Processing by TicketsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"5982a8799f911d0318054997"}
  Rendered tickets/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | ticketmongo_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('595f189d9f911d0518244d9b')}, "limit"=>1, "singleBatch"=>true}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | ticketmongo_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.0019340000000000002s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | ticketmongo_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"companies", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('596059589f911d047bd195bf')}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | ticketmongo_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001964s
  Rendered companies/_company.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered projects/_projects.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_topmenusignin.html.erb (7.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 120ms (Views: 106.0ms)


Started GET "/tickets/index/tickets.json" for ::1 at 2017-11-18 21:50:34 -0800
Processing by TicketsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"tickets"}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | ticketmongo_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"printing_tickets", "filter"=>{"project_id"=>nil}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | ticketmongo_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.0016179999999999999s
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.1ms)
```

Any help will be well received !!

Comment: This controller action is getting hits from 2 different urls and with 2 different content types. In the one with url /projects/5982a8799f911d0318054997/tickets you get project_id but in /tickets/index/tickets.json url you dont have project_id parameter. it should work if you request on /projects/5982a8799f911d0318054997/tickets.json url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET "/projects/5982a8799f911d0318054997/tickets"
```

as you can see from your `rake routes` the route for the `tickets#index` action is `/projects/:project_id/tickets` and you are passing `parameters[:project_id]` as `5982a8799f911d0318054997`. If you are passing other parameters, they will be in the `request.body`

```
GET "/tickets/index/tickets.json"
```

this route does not make sense. You need to check your router, as it is taking `parameters[:id] = 'tickets`', maybe you set your routing incorrectly.

It could look like this right now

```
GET '/tickets/index/:id'
```

and when you perform `GET request` to url `/tickets/index/tickets.json`, it will take your last input `tickets` as the `id` params

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response and this very useful information. I appreciate it !!